# Popcornjs loop in specific area

Tags: javascript, popcornjs

I have an audio that has a text that is repeated twice.

Example:" Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow."

So I want to, as the audio plays, highlight the sentence that was played on the audio.
Is there a way that I can make the popcornjs loop through the text?

For instance I would like to highlight the area where the text is inserted into twice

I tried doing this, but it doesnt work.

```
var pop = Popcorn("#greeting");

var wordTimes = {
    "w1": { start: 0.1, end: 1.5 },
    "w2": { start: 1.6, end: 14 },
    "w3": { start: 14, end: 23 },
    "w4": { start: 23, end: 39 },
    "w1": { start: 41, end: 42.4 },
    "w2": { start: 42.6, end: 44 },
    "w3": { start: 45, end: 54 },
    "w4": { start: 55, end: 68 },


};

$.each(wordTimes, function(id, time) {
     pop.footnote({
        start: time.start,
        end: time.end,
        text: '',
        target: id,
        effect: "applyclass",
        applyclass: "selected"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create the object wordTimes like this

```
wordTimes = {
    "w1": { start: 0.1, end: 1.5 },
    "w2": { start: 1.6, end: 14 },
    "w3": { start: 14, end: 23 },
    "w4": { start: 23, end: 39 },
    "w1": { start: 41, end: 42.4 },
    "w2": { start: 42.6, end: 44 },
    "w3": { start: 45, end: 54 },
    "w4": { start: 55, end: 68 },
};
```

you are changing the values of each of the times so you end up with

```
wordTimes.w1: { start: 41, end: 42.4 }
wordTimes.w2: { start: 42.6, end: 44 }
wordTimes.w3: { start: 45, end: 54 }
wordTimes.w4: { start: 55, end: 68 }
```

so only the last footnotes will appear
you can create instead a Array like this to have different elements with the same target

```
var notes = [
    {target: "w1", start: 1, end: 5 },
    {target: "w2", start: 5, end: 10 },
    {target: "w3", start: 10, end: 15 },
    {target: "w1", start: 15, end: 20 },
    {target: "w2", start: 20, end: 25 },
    {target: "w3", start: 25, end: 30 },
];
```

and change the $.each like this

```
$.each(notes, function(id, note) {
    p.footnote({
        start: note.start,
        end: note.end,
        text: '',
        target: note.target,//note.target must be a valid id 
        effect: "applyclass",
        applyclass: "selected"
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JdevM/